# The content of UItableViewCell in not updating swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tablecell

I have a custom uitableviewcell called customContactsTableViewCell. I am trying to use this code to update the uitableviewCell content

```
let cell1 = self.contactsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contacts", for: IndexPath.init(row: index, section: 0)) as! customContactsTableViewCell
cell1.cellView.image = statusFinal.1
self.contactsTableView.reloadData()
```

But nothing happens. no errors and the cellview is not updated

Comment: **where** is that code written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
let cell1 = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)) as! customContactsTableViewCell
cell1.cellView.image = statusFinal.1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are created your tableview through Storyboard just go to your tableview and set cell custom class to **customContactsTableViewCell** And you'r cell identifier should be **contacts** if everything is already setup like this, then just check your these lines.

```
cell1.cellView.image = statusFinal.1
self.contactsTableView.reloadData()
```

After reloadData it redraw tableview again and setup data in it through this tableview Delegate function.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       /// your code
    }
```

It will again update your data with old data, Just save this data **statusFinal.1** in your data model and then whenever you require reload, it will get update through updated data. Hope so you got the point, if need more info let me know.

Comment: Hi thanks now I know the problem when I call tableReload(). it reload the table with the old data. Thanks for the help though.